# Why does my array search return 0 and not 1?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am doing a very simple NSArray search as follows

```
BOOL isCashTender = [_tenderRows containsObject: @"Cash"];
```

A debug output of the array tells me there is an object in there "Cash" as seen below (its the second to last one)

```
2017-04-07 11:20:27.644551 NWMobileTill[2134:701297] tenderRowsarray:(
"<Tender: 0x17009c2a0> (entity: Tender; id: 0xd0000000002c0004 <x-coredata://BE2CD993-FDED-43CE-99A3-88597A0E8046/Tender/p11> ; data: {\n    amount = 10;\n    authCode = nil;\n    brandId = XX;\n    cardEntryMode = nil;\n    cardType = nil;\n    createdDate = \"2017-04-07T11:20:22+08:00\";\n    createdDateUtc = \"2017-04-07T03:20:22\";\n    currency = EUR;\n    extRefNo = \"Cash-In-EUR\";\n    hashedPan = nil;\n    inOrOut = IN;\n    isSynched = 0;\n    obfPan = nil;\n    orderNumber = \"1-20170407112015\";\n    status = 95;\n    synchDate = nil;\n    synchDateUtc = nil;\n    tillId = 1;\n    type = Cash;\n    userName = a;\n})"
)
```

But when I look at the debug output of my BOOL it returns 0 when I expected it to be 1, why is that?

```
2017-04-07 11:20:27.644139 NWMobileTill[2134:701297] isCashTender = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tenderRows` contains just one object, and it isn't a string `"Cash"`; it's a Tender entity.

That Tender entity may have a `type` attribute whose value is `"Cash"`, but that is not the question you asked (with `containsObject:`).

Comment: ok so how can I search for what I need inside that tender entity? I need to know if the array contains the Cash string?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is not what you asked. You asked "Why does my array search return 0 and not 1?" and I believe I answered that, correctly. You are indeed doing a "very simple NSArray search", and the result you are getting is the truth.