# How do I query an NSArray when I know the attribute name and value?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am having a hard time getting the correct query type in my NSArray search, I tried the following which failed because its not searching for the correct value

```
BOOL isCashTender = [_tenderRows containsObject: @"Cash"];
```

I want to search inside the NSArray where there is a type attribute that contains the value Cash

I don't care how many rows/objects are inside the array I simply need to know if there is at least one type attribute containing the value Cash in there

Comment: Now you are searching as if it was simple array of strings, if your array holds objects like `NSDictionary` you must implement custom search algorithm. So what objects does your array hold?

Comment: It holds objects like NStrings etc no dictionaries

Comment: From this question of you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269119/why-does-my-array-search-return-0-and-not-1 I can suppose it does contain custom objects

Comment: Yea that's a debug output of the array you are correct

Comment: You didn't pointed that you use CoreData, it may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169186/coredata-fetch-one-attribute-into-an-array, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html

Comment: Sort of helpful to get all the values, but how do I then search those values for the existence of at least one occurance of myString ?

Comment: If you get values as an array of strings then iterate and check like this `if ([test rangeOfString:@"blah"].location != NSNotFound) {
        // found
    }`

Comment: Don't get all values. Enumerate `_tenderRows` and check the property which holds "Cash".

Comment: @Willeke thats my original question, how can I enumerate the array and check the property that holds the value cash? I only need to know if there is at least one instance or not in there, I don't need anything else.

Comment: Also might be useful: [Get array of property value of each object in an array without a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9890330)

Comment: Yes so NSArray *types = [_tenderRows valueForKey:@"Type"]; will give me the different types, but I just need to know if there exists at least one type=Cash, so the resulting types array is there an easy way to just a simple check and return a BOOL if at least one instance exist?

Comment: NSArray *types = [_tenderRows valueForKey:@"Type"];
    
    BOOL isCashTender = [types containsObject: @"Cash"]; this did it for me